# Calculate percentage of unlimited items

Tags: php, mysql, math

I want to list top sellers items based on the sales history MySQL table:

```
sales(id,item)
----------------
1,Chocolate
2,Chocolate
3,Flowers
```

Will output:

```
Chocolate :: 2 Sales :: 67%
Flowers   :: 1 Sales :: 33%
```

How to do that using php?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the data from and is this more a mathematically related question or where is the problem? :E

Comment: Shouldn't the percentages be 67% and 33% rather than 75% and 25%?

Comment: This is why it's a Math issue :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of all the items you could do something like

```
$ary = array('Chocolate','Chocolate','Flowers');
$total = count($ary);
$count = array_count_values($ary);
foreach($count as $item=>$val) {
    echo '<p>'.$item.' - '.$val.' Sales - '.($val/$total*100).'%</p>';
}
```

Turns out [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) is a handy little function.

Comment: @Shikiyru Thanks for the link. I always appreciate when other people have them in posts. Was sloppy of me to exclude it.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  name, 
  round(count(*)/total_row.total*100) 
from 
  sales,
  (select count(*) as total from your_tables) as total_row 
group by sales.name;
```